# Как заставить мое android приложение взаимодействовать с интерфейсом других приложений?

Tags: android, android-studio, uiautomation

Мне нужно сделать android приложение, которое будет открываться по верх всех окон и взаимодействовать с другими приложениями, но я не понимаю как можно подобное реализовать, так как практически не имел дел с разработкой нативных андроид-приложений.

Мне нужно что-то похожее на pywinauto или pyautogui, только под андроид. При этом не важен язык, так как я немного знаком с android studio, но мои попытки найти хотя бы примерный гайд о том, как создать что-то на подобии автокликера на андроид, не увенчались успехом.

Может кто-то знает статьи, или гайды о том как реализовывается подобная "автоматизация" на андроид. Связка python + appium мне не подходит, т.к на выходе нужен не скрипт, а приложение, автоматизирующее определенные действия.

Comment: Десктопные тулы (pywinauto, pyautogui) вам тут точно не помогут. Надо смотреть мобильные типа Appium или технологию, которая лежит под Appium конкретно под Андроид. Причём, кажется, клик по приложению из приложения - довольно нестандартный сценарий. Но может даже чуть проще получится, т.к. нет кросс-девайс взаимодействия, но может быть не разрешено по умолчанию из-за security reasons. Ибо потому что так как. Но нужно подтверждение от андроидо-ведов.

Comment: Так-то в теории Python на самом Андроиде в каком-то урезанном виде можно было запустить. Где-то видел такое. Но это всё равно не полноценный хостовый скрипт скорее всего. И опять же важно понимать, под какими пермишшнами бежит приложенька.

Answer (score 0):

подходящей реализации я так и не нашел, но переделал свой проект под Appium. смартфон управляется с программы для пк, подключен по проводу. Для компиляции "управляющей" программы под windows В дистрибутив вашей программы нужно скопировать node.js и Appium, в коде прописать к этим папкам переменные окружения. Надеюсь кому-то пригодится.